# Is date modified of the files shows that the file has been used by lighttpd or not?

Tags: file, centos, lighttpd

IS date modified of the files shows that the file has been used by lighttpd or not?
I am trying to clean my hardisks becouse they are now a buttle neck problem, they are full of data, I need to know how to find the files that lighttpd didn't stream to users more that 1.5 years to delete thes becouse they are not in use.
Is date modefided is the best solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.  Date modified is not a good indication of access.

If you have web logs, you should consult those for what was served by lighttpd.

Absent that, you might look at atime (access time) instead of mtime (modification time) if your server is configured to track atimes and you do not have anything crawling the volume which would update the atimes.  (You'll have to look at your server yourself to answer that question.  Nobody can answer it for you.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Can you please write a sample of atime check for /media/mp4 ? to check witch is not accessed for the past year?

Comment: `find /media/mp4 -atime +365`